# Random rearrangement of objects within a grid in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

I've got a set of tiles and I want to create a pattern out of it. Normally, this would produce a pattern with a single rectangle of these coloured tiles, which would give me noticeable repetitions.

To avoid that I have to duplicate the rectangle several times and rearrange single tiles manually to hide repetitions, which takes hell lots of time.

So, here's the question. Is there a way, a plugin, a script, which will make my life easier? Something, which would randomly generate a large table out of the given set of tiles?

[image]

Comment: I'm not aware of anything... but there maybe script out there. My guess would be it's possible via scripting to randomly arrange symbols in a grid.

Comment: Surely it is, but I know nothing about scripting for Illustrator

Answer (score 1):

How many do you have to repeat randomly? I would mess with the align tool. Just throw bunch of symbols on the page randomly and then work at the grid. You can align rows randomly very quick this way. You could also start with the symbol sprayer tool and then align those into rows.

Comment: A few blocks of tiles shown in the picture

Answer (score 0):

I know the new update for the plug-in from Astute graphics named "[ColliderScribe](http://www.astutegraphics.com/software/colliderscribe/)" added a "random space fill" feature based on your selection. There may be a way to utilize that plug-in for what you're looking for. They also have a 14-day free trial (no restrictions) if you needed it for a quick project.

Other than that you may be able to use this [Script Random selection](http://www.scriptopedia.org/en/js-illustrator/53-random-objects-selection.html) To help out in creating a more random effect. Then using the align tools to grid everything up again.

Hope this helps.